# How to find all not matching elements in XPath expression of XSL template?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

This is my XML:

```
<f>
  <a>10</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>4</a>
  <a>13</a>
  <b>55</b>
  <b>4</b>
</f>
```

I'm trying to match elements `<b/>` which are not equal to `<a/>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="b[. != //a]">
    <xsl:text>found!</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, it doesn't work. I believe, my expression `. != //a` is wrong, since `//a` matches only the first occurrence of `<a/>`. What is the right expression?

It's a test sample, please don't suggest other possible ways of solving this task. I only need a fix to the XPath expression.

Comment: So which `b` elements do you want to match, which ones not? Most XPath users using e.g. `. != $sequence` want rather `not(. = $sequence)` e.g. `not(. = //a)` i.e. the current `.` item is not equal to any `a`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen this is exactly what I was looking for! Please, make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most XPath users using e.g. `. != $sequence` want rather `not(. = $sequence)` e.g. `not(. = //a)` i.e. the current `.` item is not equal to any `a` element.

Answer (score 2):

The smart (and efficient) way to do this is to use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="a" match="a" use="." />

<!-- other templates -->

<xsl:template match="b[not(key('a', .))]">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To further clarify the reason why your attempt did not work is that you are comparing sequences. This comparison is [defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-general-comparisons) to return `true`

> if there is a pair of atomic values, one in the first operand sequence and the other in the second operand sequence, that have the required **magnitude relationship**.

IOW, your expression `b[. != //a]` returns `true` for any `b` that is unequal to at least one `a` - which in your example means for all of them.